# LNK2005 Error when trying to override global new and delete operators

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, linker-errors

I have a C++ project that has been compiling and linking without problems. Recently we added code to override the global new and delete operators and now the project fails to link with the error:

> error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined.

I am aware of MS KB148652 and have done what it suggested -- I've placed Nafxcwd.lib and Libcmtd.lib in the Additional Dependencies and Ignore Specific Libary lists. Actually they were already there since I had to add them to eliminate other previous linker errors. I've made sure that the first include in all .cpp files is stdafx.h (as KB148652 suggests) but nothing seems to work.

If anyone can suggest another approach or some direction I haven't tried I'd appreciate knowing about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `new` replacement defined inline? That could be your problem.

Comment: Override the operator on the command line. That will show you where else is trying to override them.

Comment: Make sure to build everything with the same calling convention (__cdecl in your case) - make sure your make clean is really clean
- Build test code into your base package that tests out global new and delete replacement - Read up on calling conventions

Comment: Use the "force include" option in all the Visual Studio projects to make sure that the corresponding include is first in every C++ implementation file. Do not try to use this in debug, only in release.

Comment: Try renaming your new/delete as my_new/my_delete, then use #defines to expand all uses of new/delete to my_new/my_delete? Not sure if this would work but a stab in the dark here

Answer (score 1):

Clean the whole project and try to rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in c++ , overloaded operators are not inherited through the class hierarchy, so try to completely redefine a separate copy of new and delete in each derived class without referring to the base class's definition using base_class::operator new,
i hope i could help you